# Preventing "Restore Tab" from accessing Session Storage

Tags: html, security, session, session-storage

sessionStorage is great for easily and quickly saving session-related data for the lifetime of a web page session. However, when a browser tab is closed, but then re-opened by anybody with access to the "Recent Tabs" section of a browser, they can once again access the session data.

Is there any way to flag some session storage data as "not to be saved when the tab is restored" or should I try something else? For example, will a session cookie perform more safely in this instance?

Comment: You should expire the session in a reasonable time as the server can’t know whether a cookie was send from an active browser session or a restored one.

Comment: Are you asking about the case where the user quits their browser completely and launches it again later, and the browser remembers the tabs that were open?  Or the case where the user clicks the X on a tab, then says "oops" and recovers it from the "recently closed tabs" menu?

Comment: @Gumbo: The server shouldn't be getting the cookie at all, actually. This is a security requirement I'm afraid, the user needs to be assured that certain personal details will not travel across the wire.

Comment: @Wyzard: The case where user clicks X on a tab then says "oops". I know it may sound like I am hurting the user experience, but it's also possible that the user won't say "oops", but someone else using the browser window later will have a look.

Comment: You can't control the browser regarding how it handles session cookies, e. g., whether it decides to store a session cookie beyond its lifetime (e. g., it restores it after a shutdown). Educate your users to disable such features or to use the incognito mode.

Comment: Hi @basicallydan, I am experiencing the same problem. Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use a Session Cookie.  If you do not set the `Expires` or `Max-Age` attributes, the browser is instructed to delete the cookie once the browser has been closed.  However, this only works once the entire browser window has been closed.

Cookies are scoped to the entire browser, not to individual tabs.  If the browser has been closed, and then the tab is restored from history, a Session Cookie will be gone.  If a tab is closed and re-opened with the browser not being closed, your session cookie will persist.

**Update**: The Firefox "restore session" and Chrome "Continue where I left off" features pretty much ignore the spec (RFC-2109). Bear that in mind and use at your own risk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aurand. So, this is pretty much the problem I'm trying to solve. I need the information to disappear as soon as the tab is closed, but to exist across page refreshes. Do you know of a native feature which I can make use of for this?

Comment: I am getting quite late to the party here, but since I'm facing this very problem, I can confirm that Firefox and Chrome indeed DO restore cookies (even "secure" ones, since FF4) when the "restore session" functionality is used, even if the browser has been shut. This makes this answer pretty wrong nowadays (I guess it was right when it was posted, though). Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Session_cookies

Comment: @sensei Yes, the FF "restore session" and Chrome "continue where I left off" are pretty blatant breaches of RFC-2109 which specifies the "expected" behaviour.  I've updated my answer with that warning.