# Detect when browser restores a session

Tags: google-chrome, session-storage, sessionstorage

#### Background

I would like to run some code when the browser (not tab) closes. Failing that I would like to run the code the first time after the close. Normally session storage is cleared on close so I was originally going to use that, but found it is not cleared if you use the "continue where you left off" option (I'm focusing on Chrome for now).

### Question

This made me wonder: is there any way to detect when a browser restores a session? I'm looking at chrome specifically, but a cross-browser answer would be even better.

Comment: `Suggestions also welcome for how to detect a browser (not tab) close` you need **one** question per Q&A, please ask another question.

Comment: @cybermonkey I only asked one actual question, but I'm removing the comment anyway just to ensure a focused response. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871773/preventing-restore-tab-from-accessing-session-storage?rq=1) suggests using a cookie with no `Max-Age` and no `Expires`. These cookies are deleted once the browser is fully closed.

If that's not sufficient, you may be able to combine it with some behavior in a [BeforeUnload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) event handler.

Comment: Thanks but those are related to the session and tab close respectively. The session is not always cleared when the browser is closed. That's what led me to ask this question.